# print loops results in differents folder

Tags: r, loops, printing, resultset

I have results for n variables from different loops; I am trying to save the results for each variable in a CSV format inside a folder with the name of the variable. For this:

1. I created different folders

```
set.seed(1)
met <- c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5", "y6", "y7",
         "y8", "y9", "y10")
nomedir <-'results_'
for (i in seq_along(met)){
  refdir <-paste0(nomedir, met[i])
 
  if(file.exists(refdir)){
    unlink(refdir, recursive = TRUE,force = TRUE)
  }
  dir.create(refdir)
  cat('I create ', refdir)
}
```

2. Run the loops

```
#loops for y4 - y7
library(olsrr)
for (i in 10:13) {
  model_components<-lm(data=pheno2, pheno2[[i]]~a + b + c + d + e)
  both.p_components<-ols_step_both_p(model_components, penter=0.05, prem=0.1)
  print(names(pheno2)[i])
  print(both.p_components)
}
#loop for y9 - y10
library(olsrr)
for (i in 15:16) {
  model_mine<-lm(data=pheno2, pheno2[[i]]~a + b + c )
  both.p_mine<-ols_step_both_p(model_mine, penter=0.05, prem=0.1)
  print(names(pheno2)[i])
  print(both.p_mine)
}
```

I would like results from y4 to be stored in folder y4, results from y5 in folder y5... and so on. Any idea?